# No handler for type [circle] declared on field

Tags: elasticsearch

My question is, as simple as it gets: What am I doing wrong? There should be a type:"circle" supported on elasticsearch 5.3.1, but nevertheless I get this error-message, when creating an index.

In case I remove just that one field (of type circle) the index will be created without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I found it: "circle" is a "geo_shape", so when creating the index the mapping has to be "geo_shape" not "circle".

```
    "some_location": {
      "type": "geo_shape",
      "tree": "quadtree",
      "precision": "1m"
    }
```